# int8 header file not found during compilation

Tags: gcc, gcc4.7

Trying to compile a simple c program and get error.

```
In file included from /opt/local/lib/gcc47/gcc/x86_64-apple-         darwin13/4.7.3/include/stdint.h:3:0,
             from ecl/config.h:134,
             from ecl/ecl.h:35,
             from main.c:2:
/opt/local/lib/gcc47/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13/4.7.3/include-fixed/stdint.h:27:32: fatal error: sys/_types/_int8_t.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

What is this error and how can I fix it? From what I gather int8 etc. is typedefined in stdint.h but there's no mention of it in types.h or _types.h. Do I just add these definitions in there or... really lost here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install IBM® Informix® ESQL/C.
The following BIGINT functionality is available only to users of IBM® Informix® ESQL/C. To use these functions, ESQL/C users will need to manually link their C code to the ESQL/C libraries.
Ref - https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rbd/9.5.1?topic=libraries-bigint-functions-c
and https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=programming-esqlc-header-files